# SQL - how to retrieve unique value(nvarchar) in a join table?

Tags: sql, join, distinct

I am trying to display all columns for two join table but only retrieve unique value from one of the columns (i.e. `antsDescriptionCode`) which has a datatype of `nvarchar`.

Can anyone please help? Thanks.

My current query on allows me display all columns for two join table with some condition:

```
select c.*, a.* 
from cats c
join ants a on c.ctypeid = a.atypeid
where 
     (c.CatsNo like 'cat4%'
   or c.CatsNo like 'cat7%'
   or c.CatsNo like 'cat8%')
   and a.antsflagged = 0 
   and a.antsDescriptionCode in ('type a', 'type b', 'type  c')!
```

[Refer to image for current get and expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIVcz.png)

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Can you add an example of the output you currently get, and the output that you want to get?

Comment: Hi @Blorgbeard 
I have updated my question. fyi, I am new here, not sure how to display a table in my question / comments so I have uploaded a file for your reference. Thanks.

Comment: What type of database?  AntsDescriptionCode corresponds to multiple records, how should it determine which record you want returned for each AntsDescriptionCode?  It's a little unclear what you're looking for.

Comment: @ayuicyi that's ok - people usually just put tables in as text in a code block and manually space them out. There's no support for better tables than that unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Microsoft SQL Server, you can do something like this:

```
select * from (
select 
    c.*, a.*,
    row_number() over (partition by a.antsDescriptionCode order by CatsNo) [row]
from cats c
join ants a on c.ctypeid = a.atypeid
where 
     (c.CatsNo like 'cat4%'
   or c.CatsNo like 'cat7%'
   or c.CatsNo like 'cat8%')
   and a.antsflagged = 0 
   and a.antsDescriptionCode in ('type a', 'type b', 'type  c')
) q where q.row=1
```

This will give you the first row (ordered by `catsno`) for every distinct `antsDescriptionCode`.

It will also give you an extra column (called "row") of `1` values. To get rid of that, replace the first `*` with the actual list of columns.

Comment: Thanks. I am wondering where to define q as i am getting an error "Incorrect syntax near 'q'".

Comment: Are you sure you copy and pasted the query exactly? I don't get a syntax error on my computer. Are you using Microsoft SQL Server? What version?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008. It still returns the same error though. I am wondering what have I done wrong.

Comment: I'm on SQL Server 2008 as well. That query copy+pasted into SSMS works for me if I create the appropriate tables - I'm not sure why it would fail for you.. can you run the query if you remove the first and last lines?

Answer (score 0):

Because you're joining on an arbitrary `TypeID` that is shared by multiple rows in both tables, you'll need to define your data further. What determines which of the many Ant rows is associated with that Cat besides its type? Do you only want to return the highest AntsID for a given type? Defining the relationship further will create for an easier, more robust solution. Without that defined, other answers to this question will certainly suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am actually quite new to SQL so I might need some help to elaborate further. It would be good if you could explain to me by using this examples. Thank you.

Comment: I want to return unique value for column 'antsDescriptionCode'.

Comment: Ok, but your antsDescriptionCode is not unique within its table. You've got 'type a' written in all ATypeID 50, but three different AntsIDs in there. If you want uniqueness, it needs to be 1 ID, 1 TypeID, and 1 DescriptionCode. The next ID will have a different TypeID and a different DescriptionCode, etc.